# How to send data via bluetooth to Pi pico

Tags: python, c, bluetooth, raspberry-pi-pico, pybluez

I need a way to send data to and from my pi pico via bluetooth.
Here is the program I'm running on my pc.

Note: Everything on the pi is working correctly (tested with a bt serial terminal)

```
import bluetooth as bt

print("Scanning Bluetooth Devices....")

devices = bt.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)

for addr, name in devices:
    print("%s : %s" % (name, addr))

dev_name = input("Enter device name: ")

dev = ""
check = False

for addr, name in devices:
    if dev_name == name:
        dev = addr
        check = True

if not check:
    print("Device Name Invalid!")
else:
    print("Attempting to connect to %s : %s" % (dev_name, dev))

hostMACAddress = dev
port = 3
backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = bt.BluetoothSocket(bt.RFCOMM)
s.bind((hostMACAddress, port))
s.listen(backlog)
try:
    client, clientInfo = s.accept()
    while 1:
        data = client.recv(size)
        if data:
            print(data)
            client.send(data) # Echo back to client
except: 
    print("Closing socket")
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

It doesn't throw any errors but I don't get anything printed to the terminal when the pi should send "R"

Edit: Here is the working code for anyone interested :)

```
import bluetooth as bt

print("Scanning Bluetooth Devices....")

devices = bt.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)

for addr, name in devices:
    print("%s : %s" % (name, addr))

dev_name = input("Enter device name: ")

dev = ""
check = False

for addr, name in devices:
    if dev_name == name:
        dev = addr
        check = True

if not check:
    print("Device Name Invalid!")
else:
    print("Sending data to %s : %s" % (dev_name, dev))

hostMACAddress = dev
port = 1
backlog = 1
size = 8
s = bt.BluetoothSocket(bt.RFCOMM)
try:
    s.connect((hostMACAddress, port))
except:
    print("Couldn't Connect!")
s.send("T")
s.send("E")
s.send("S")
s.send("T")
s.send(".")
s.close()
```

Comment: I found some info on working with Bluetooth in python but it seems you need the MAC address of the Bluetooth device you want to talk to. Under the settings for the HC-05 (Pi Pico) it says the MAC address is unavailable. Does anyone know how to access it or if it needs to be configured by the pico on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward (but not the most efficient way) is to convert the array of integer to a delimited C string and send it the way you are sending "Ready".
Let assume the array delimiters are "[" and "]" then the following array

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
```

can be converted to a string like the following

```
char str[] = "[010203]";
```

To convert array of integer to the delimited string you can do the following:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
int str_length = 50; // Change the length of str based on your need.
char str[str_length] = {0};
int char_written = 0;

char_written = sprintf(str,'[');
for (int i = 0; i< sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int) - 1; i++){
    char_written = sprintf(&str[char_written], "%02d", arr[i]);
char_written = sprintf(&str[char_written], ']');
```

Now you can use your existing code to send this string. In the receiving end, you need to process the string based on "[", "]", and the fact that each integer has width of 2 in the string.

Edit: Converting array to string and send the string via bluetooth via python.

To convert an array to string in python the following will do the job

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a_string = "[" + "".join(f"{i:02d}" for i in a) + "]"
```

To send this string via python over bluetooth you need to use [PyBlues](https://pybluez.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

First you need to find the MAC address of the pico bluetooth

```
import bluetooth
# Make sure the only bluetooth device around is the pico.
devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
print(devices)
```

Now that you know the MAC address, you need to connect to it

```
bt_mac = "x:x:x:x:x:x" # Replace with yours.
port = 1
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
```

Know you can send strings like

```
sock.send(a_string.encode())
```

Finally, in the end of your python program close the socket

```
sock.close()
```

PS: I do not have bluetooth available to test it but it should work.

Comment: Good tips but my issue lies in sending the strings to the pi. The "Ready." transmission isn't of much use to me besides showing the bluetooth connection works. I need help writing code to send each int (on the pc) and receive (on the pi)

Comment: If you are able to send "Ready", and see it on the other side, I assume you have figured out the way to send and receive strings via Bluetooth.

Then the easiest way to send numbers, is just what I mentioned (converting them to delimited string and send it as string. Converting back the delimited string to integers is straightforward in python.

If you are in the process of figuring out the Bluetooth part, I think I can still help.

Comment: So I have figured out how to send and receive but on the PC end I'm using a serial terminal which only allows me to send one line at a time and I have to manually type it out. This is far too tedious for sending a whole array of numbers. I haven't been able to figure out how to connect to my pico via a python code running on my pc.